# Почему для заголовка h1 у меня не работают margin и padding?

Tags: html, css

```css
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 60 px;
        font-family: "Raleway";
        color: #686868;
        font-family:"sans-serif";
    }
    header{
        margin-left: 190 px;
        padding: 50 px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
   <h1>COOKING FOOD </h1> 
    </header>  
    <div>
  <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c852124/v852124380/1456e4/Icw8qDLicos.jpg" alt="Fruits" height="100%">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно отделять пробелом единицы измерения:

```css
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-family: "Raleway";
        color: #686868;
        font-family:"sans-serif";
    }
    header{
        margin-left: 190px;
        padding: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
   <h1>COOKING FOOD </h1> 
    </header>  
    <div>
  <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c852124/v852124380/1456e4/Icw8qDLicos.jpg" alt="Fruits" height="100%">
    </div>
```

Comment: @l2banners, 6 секунд =)